# Why iBGP speaker should not modify next hop address?

Tags: routing, bgp, networking

I understand the concept of "Split Horizon" that an iBGP router A learns an external route from an iBGP router B, thereafter, iBGP router B will not advertise the same route to other iBGP routers.

However, why would an iBGP router NOT modify the NEXT_HOP address when advertising an external route to other iBGP peers? I understand it is a rule of iBGP but what purpose does it serve?

Comment: "_an iBGP router A learns an external route from an iBGP router B, thereafter, iBGP router B will not advertise the same route to other iBGP routers._" No, the rule is an iBGP speaker cannot advertise a route learned from iBGP to another iBGP speaker. An external (eBGP) route is not a route from iBGP. Router A learning an eBGP route advertises it to router B, and router B can advertise an eBGP route to other iBGP speakers. If router A has a directly connected network and advertises that to router B vis iBGP, then router B cannot advertise that to other iBGP speakers because the Origin is iBGP.

Comment: @RonMaupin I appreciate your response but as far as I know, 

Router E -- eBGP -- Router A --> Advertise a route (10.10.10.0/24)
Router A --iBGP -- Router B --> Advertise the route (10.10.10.0/24)
Router B --iBGP -- Router C  --> Will not advertise route (10.10.10.0/24)

[Reference 1](https://learnduty.com/articles/bgp-split-horizon-rule-explained-configuration/?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=bgp-split-horizon-rule-explained-configuration)
[Reference 2](https://www.ccexpert.us/bgp-4/route-reflector-splithorizon-rules.html)

Comment: for what reason would you modify NEXT_HOP?

Comment: @Effie I am trying to understand the reason behind the rule that why an IBGP router should not modify the next-hop address while advertising to another IBGP router? 

Since the Split Horizon rule is used to avoid loop inside an Autonomous system, what kind of problem it would solve by not updating next hop IP address?

Comment: first of all, your split horizon rule will not work if you have route reflectors (see your reference 2). BGP NEXT_HOP is used as a part of decision process (see sec 9.1.2.2 of [rfc4271](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4271.html#section-9.1.2.2)), so if you change next-hop the result would change. I am not sure how, but it will change. I think this is what @manish-ma explained. Also, you might find [this link](https://blog.ipspace.net/2011/08/bgp-next-hop-processing.html) helpful -- see last two sections.

Comment: @Effie From the link = _"All routers within an autonomous system are assumed to be able to reach the same set of subnets. Consequently, when an AS edge router propagates external BGP prefixes to internal BGP peers, it does not change the BGP next hop."_ 

What if the AS doesn't have any IGP protocol running, and the IBGP routers are not configured with the next-hop-self command either? The AS is running only IBGP and all routers are connected in a Mess topology. In this scenario, Will an IBGP router update the next hop, while advertising prefixes to another IBGP router?

Comment: the option AS does not run any IGP is not a scenario considered by BGP spec. BGP assumes that an AS runs an IGP (maybe static routes would suffice, but there must be routing). if you again consider sec 9.1.2 you may see that there are things like IGP weights and recursive route lookups (i.e., to the IGP) in the selection procedure. I think the next section in my reference (iBGP Next Hop Design Rules) covers what you are asking.

Comment: also note: section 5.1.3 of [rfc4271](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4271.html#section-5.1.3):  When sending a message to an internal peer, if the route is not locally originated, the BGP speaker **SHOULD NOT modify the
         NEXT_HOP attribute unless it has been explicitly configured to
         announce its own IP address as the NEXT_HOP**. So, yes, it is up to the AS, what they configure their routers to.

Answer (score 5):

The reason for this rule is loop prevention.  If path attributes which affect the bestpath selection are modified during iBGP-to-iBGP route distribution, loop-free bestpath selection is not guaranteed.

In practice, this rule is broken in many networks and care is taken to align routing policy and network topology choices to prevent loops.  Further, when modern MPLS tunneling methods are used, for example labeled-unicast, it is possible to manipulate iBGP-to-iBGP routes without worrying about loops, because a PE1--P2--P3--PE4 topology where P2 bestpaths to PE4 and P3 bestpaths to PE1 isn't a problem so long as the traffic is tunneled; traffic loop does not occur.

Answer (score -1):

One reason, I can think of, is when you have two exit points from your local AS. In this case setting next-hop-self on one of the boundary routers will change BGP's path selection to only use this preferred path - instead of load balancing via 2 exit points.

You can also enable BGP PIC edge for fast convergence in case there is a primary and backup paths towards the unmodified next-hop. If you used next-hop-self this functionality couldn't be utilized.

Comment: next-hop-self is the solution to the IBGP rule, which is _"the BGP speaker SHOULD NOT modify the NEXT_HOP attribute unless it has been explicitly configured to announce its own IP address as the NEXT_HOP."_ 

I am trying to understand what kind the problem does it solve by adding such a rule?
Does it avoid loop or anything else? How?

Comment: Usually you don't need to advertise youself as next-hop when advertising routes to other iBGP neighbors, since it is assumed that all next hops within an AS are reachable via some IGP protocol. Also if you are using a route reflector you probably don't want it in the data-path - so also you generally avoid setting it as next-hop.

Answer (score -2):

I will tell in the simple way, IBGP routers will form the IBGP sessions within the same AS that means all the routers in the IBGP are in the same AS and they will assume that they can reach any subnet through the IGP protocol running, so it wont change the next hop when advertised the prefixes to other IBGP neighbors.

Regards,
Ganapareddy Sudhakar